# Parse html in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for example I have html on my page (which populated dynamically):

```
<ul>
 <li>Country</li>
 <li>State</li>
 <li>City</li>
</ul>
```

And want to send this to the db after pressing the button.

I used `ng-model="modelName"` for inputs, but what I can use for simple text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just read it with document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML ?